# How to solve equation containing multiple arctan's in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, trigonometry, control-theory

I need to solve the following equation for a control systems course;

```
-atan((sqrt(319)*x/9 - 4)/(x - 2)) - atan((sqrt(319)*x/9 + 4)/(x - 2)) + atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 2))) + atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 4))) + 180 = 0
```

I tried using the following python program to determine the values of x;

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

x = sy.symbols('x')

sy.solve(sy.atan(((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x)/(x + 2)) + sy.atan(((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x)/(x + 4)) - sy.atan((((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x) + 4)/(x - 2)) - sy.atan((((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x) - 4)/(x - 2)) + 180, x)
```

But I keep getting the following error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-52038f2d514c> in <module>()
      5 x = sy.symbols('x')
      6 
----> 7 sy.solve(sy.atan(((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x)/(x + 2)) + 
sy.atan(((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x)/(x + 4)) - sy.atan((((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x) + 4)/(x - 2)) - sy.atan((((sy.sqrt(319)/9)*x) - 4)/(x - 2)) + 180, x)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1063     
###########################################################################
   1064     if bare_f:
-> 1065         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
   1066     else:
   1067         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in _solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1632 
   1633     if result is False:
-> 1634         raise NotImplementedError('\n'.join([msg, not_impl_msg % f]))
   1635 
   1636     if flags.get('simplify', True):

NotImplementedError: multiple generators [atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 2))), atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 4))), atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x - 2)) + 4/(x - 2)), atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x - 2)) - 4/(x - 2))]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -atan((sqrt(319)*x/9 - 4)/(x - 2)) - atan((sqrt(319)*x/9 + 4)/(x - 2)) + atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 2))) + atan(sqrt(319)*x/(9*(x + 4))) + 180
```

Is there a way around this issue or can Python not solve a complicated expression with multiple trigonometric functions?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try nsolve to get a numerical approximation.

Comment: I've tried using nsolve but I get a "TypeError: cannot create mpf from x" error or a "ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (32400 > 2.1684e-19)
Try another starting point or tweak arguments." error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could not find a way around the error:

```
TypeError: cannot create mpf from x
```

Instead since this is trigonometry, the answer must be in the range 0 - 360, if you're using degrees. I use a for-loop to iterate through this range and return an approximate solution.